# What the key generate-id( preceding-sibling:: ... meaning XSL 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following xsl
:

```
<xsl:key name="kEventslegal" 
         match="HISTORY_EVENT"
         use="concat(generate-id(
                        preceding-sibling::HISTORY_EVENT[
                           @Name='Item Acceptance Review event NO by Legal'
                        ][last()]
                     ),
                     '+',
                     generate-id(
                        following-sibling::HISTORY_EVENT[
                           @Name='Legal Report done'
                        ][1])
                     )"/>
```

the xml:

```
<ROOT>
     <HISTORY_EVENT Name="Item Acceptance Review event NO by Legal" 
                    EVENTSUBJECT="Item Acceptance Review event NO by Legal">
          <EVENT_TIMESTAMP>31/01/2011 11:08:27</EVENT_TIMESTAMP>
          <EVENT_STATE>opend</EVENT_STATE>
          <EVENT_ROLE>Legal Unit Specialist</EVENT_ROLE>
          <EVENT_USER>legal.test</EVENT_USER>
          <EVENT_TYPE>normal</EVENT_TYPE>
          <EVENT_PROCESS>Item Acceptance Review event NO by Legal Unit Specialist</EVENT_PROCESS>
          <EVENT_MESSAGE>Item Acceptance Review event NO by Legal Unit Specialist legal.test</EVENT_MESSAGE>
        </HISTORY_EVENT>
........
</ROOT>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like @Dimitre or @Alejandro had answered a question from one of your colleagues. Joking, of course.

Comment: In short it makes an unique string. It is built from unique identifiers of two element nodes and a delimeter. First node is the last (in reverse document order) preceding sibling HISTORY_EVENT element with a name attribute, which value is "Item ...". Second is the first following sibling HISTORY_EVENT elevent with a name attribute, which value is "Legal...".

Comment: Duh. It's pretty much already written in code. My guess it is a flat structure solver.

Comment: The question is more like where this key is being used.

Comment: @Haroldis: Looks like @Flack is right: maybe searching for start and end marks for grouping... But it's some how strange, because last preceding sibling like `preceding-sibling::HISTORY_EVENT[...][last()]` is in fact first child as in `../HISTORY_EVENT[...][1]` (except for first, that it wouldn't have a preceding...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `<xsl:key>` identifies all `HISTORY_EVENT` elements that are surrounded by two specific `HISTORY_EVENT` elements:

- The first  -- having a `Name` attribute with value: `'Item Acceptance Review event NO by Legal'`
- The last -- having a `Name` attribute with value: `'Legal Report done'`

**To summarize**: looks like all entries for all legal report with review result NO.